# jQuery selectors rows and columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors

If this gives me the 5th column (td) in row (tr) identified by id=row5,

```
var myCell = $('#row5 td:th-child(6)');
```

what statement would give me the 7th column in the following row?

Comment: That would give you nothing `:th-child()` isnt valid `:nth-child()` is. Even if it was `:nth-child()` that would give you row 5 col 6 not row 5 col 5...

Comment: if I had a id='row6', but I don't, although I suppose I could. I am really looking for a "next tr" type syntax.

Comment: What about `$('#row5:next td:th-child(6));`?

Comment: exAaron - exactly the syntax I was looking for. Let me see if it will work.

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge oops, the correct intra-selector syntax, I believe, is  `$('#row5 + tr td:nth-child(7)');`, as in the answer provided by @Cokegod below.

Comment: This works... "'#row5 + tr td:nth-child(7)');"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#row5 + tr td:nth-child(7)');
```